# Console don't export any scraped data

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to learn scrapy and python. Url I use is  https://www.riddles.com/jokes-and-riddles In conda console response.css works fine and extracts the "Riddle" words. But when trying to run spyder in Visual Studio it loads everything and runs but no data is being exported.

Spider

```
import scrapy
from ..items import BookItem 

class BookSpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "book_spider"
    start_urls = (
        'https://www.riddles.com/jokes-and-riddles',
    )

def parse(self, response) :
    items = BookItem()

    title_name = response.css('span.hidden-print::text').extract()
    
    items['title_name'] = title_name
        
    yield items
```

items

```
import scrapy


class BookItem(scrapy.Item):

    title_name = scrapy.Field()
    pass
```

console

```
(scraper) C:\Users\Naked\tutorial\book\book>scrapy crawl book_spider
2019-05-02 14:07:04 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.1.1 started (bot: book)
2019-05-02 14:07:04 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'book.spiders',
'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['book.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': 'book'}
2019-05-02 14:07:05 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats']
2019-05-02 14:07:05 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.chunked.ChunkedTransferMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2019-05-02 14:07:05 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2019-05-02 14:07:05 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2019-05-02 14:07:05 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2019-05-02 14:07:05 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2019-05-02 14:07:05 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6024
2019-05-02 14:07:06 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.riddles.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2019-05-02 14:07:07 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.riddles.com/jokes-and-riddles> (referer: None)
2019-05-02 14:07:07 [scrapy] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://www.riddles.com/jokes-and-riddles> (referer: None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Naked\Anaconda3\envs\scraper\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py",
line 651, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\Naked\Anaconda3\envs\scraper\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spiders\__init__.py", line 76, in parse
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError
2019-05-02 14:07:07 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2019-05-02 14:07:07 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 453,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 32139,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 2, 11, 7, 7, 302220),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 3,
 'log_count/ERROR': 1,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'spider_exceptions/NotImplementedError': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 2, 11, 7, 5, 824498)}
2019-05-02 14:07:07 [scrapy] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Sorry for a lot of code, just wanted to explain everything.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the spider code pasted here is well indented? Because if it doesn't it's where lies your error.

Python uses indentation to delimiter the scope of a class or function, in your code the `parse` method is outside the scope of your class spider.

If you are familiar with other languages this is the equivalent of doing this:

```
class Example {
}

function parse {
}
```

instead of

```
class Example {
    function parse {
    }
}
```

If you see the `ERROR` log you can sort of figure out what is happening:

> File
> "C:\Users\Naked\Anaconda3\envs\scraper\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spiders_*init*_.py",
> line 76, in parse

> raise NotImplementedError

Not the best error message, because it is point to a file outside your project, but gives you a hint.

So the solution is indent your code like this:

```
class BookSpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "book_spider"
    start_urls = (
        'https://www.riddles.com/jokes-and-riddles',
    )

    def parse(self, response) :
        items = BookItem()

        title_name = response.css('span.hidden-print::text').extract()

        items['title_name'] = title_name

        yield items
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the given code, also the css was returning 'riddle' as title for every riddles.Also remember to add allowed_domains and use [   ]

```py
import scrapy
from ..items import BookItem


class BookSpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'book_spider'
    allowed_domains = ['www.riddles.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.riddles.com/jokes-and-riddles']


    def parse(self, response) :
        items = BookItem()

        title_name = response.xpath('//blockquote[@class="orange_dk_blockquote hidden-print"]/p/text()').extract()

        items['title_name'] = title_name

        yield items
```